# Post bulk records to Airtable using C# and REST API

Tags: c#, airtable

I'm new to APIs and JSONs, and I still learning.

I'm trying to use Airtable APIs to POST some Records.

I succeeded to POST a single record using the following code

```
public static async Task POstData()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api.airtable.com/v0/APPID/Streams"))
            {
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer APIKEY");
                request.Content = new StringContent("{\"records\": [{  \"fields\": {    \"URL\": \"https://www.omnycontent.com/d/playlist/XXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/podcast.rss\"  }}]}");

                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I need to be able to POST more than one row.

I have created the model to hold the data but I'm totally lost while trying to initialize this object from a DataGridView or even a list to send it as a body in my request.

Model Code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace VLCStreamer
{
    public class StreamsPOSTModel
    {
        public class Fields
        {
            [JsonPropertyName("URL")]
            [JsonInclude]
            public string URL { get; set; }
        }

        public class Record
        {
            [JsonPropertyName("fields")]
            [JsonInclude]
            public Fields fields { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            [JsonPropertyName("records")]
            [JsonInclude]
            public List<Record> records { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

JSON sample

```
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "recpTA8iMRdYKZx1P",
      "fields": {
        "URL": "https://www.omnycontent.com/d/playlist/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/c5f3e198-0670-4a15-a394-ac2a01343be8/..."
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "recH5nvTKSX53uiL9",
      "fields": {
        "URL": "https://www.omnycontent.com/d/playlist/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-ab4a0031815f/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/..."
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "recVL79CLye2ir6tV",
      "fields": {
        "URL": "https://www.omnycontent.com/d/playlist/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-ab4a0031815f/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/..."
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a Loop to process each Record within the Records List...?

For Each Record in Records

```
 request.Content = new StringContent("{\"records\": [{  \"fields\": {    
 \"URL\": \"https://www.omnycontent.com/d/playlist/1bde254c-01ad-4de7-8b97- 
 ab4900ff8193/40209fae-1b4a-49d6-9696-ab4a0031815f/c5f3e198-0670-4a15-a394- 
 ac2a01343be8/podcast.rss\"  }}]}");

 request.Content.Headers.ContentType = 
 MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

 var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

Next

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).